# Not able to bind video URL to angularjs directive with video.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, video.js

I am trying to bind video URL fetched from `loopback` angular sdk. Below is the definition of template:

```
<div class="row">               
    <div class="row offset2" ><div>{{videoStreamer}}</div>
         <video id='myVideo' videodir controls class="video-js vjs-default-skin" >
            <source src="{{video.videoURL}}"  type="rtmp/mp4" />
        </video>
    </div>
    <div>sdfeasfds{{videoURL}}</div>
</div>
```

I am getting data for videoStreamer, videoURL only in `div`. But not getting videoURL in `<source src="{{video.videoURL}}"  type="rtmp/mp4" />`. Below is the controller and directive.

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('ClipDetailController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'Clip','$timeout','$sce', function($rootScope, $scope,
      $state, $stateParams, Clip, $timeout, $sce){
        console.log('into detail  controller'+ JSON.stringify($stateParams));
        $scope.clipDetails = [];
        $scope.videoProtocol = "";
        $scope.videoStreamer = "";
        $scope.videoFile = "";
        $scope.videoURL = "";           

        var clipId = $stateParams.id;
        //getClipById(clipId);

        var vm = this;
        vm.clipDetails = [];
        $scope.promiseReturn = activate();

        function activate(){
            return Clip.findById({id:clipId}).$promise.then(function(result){
                vm.clipDetails = result;
                console.log(vm.clipDetails);

                $scope.videoProtocol = vm.clipDetails.stream.protocol;
                $scope.videoStreamer = vm.clipDetails.stream.streamer;
                $scope.videoFile = vm.clipDetails.stream.file;

                $scope.videoURL = $scope.videoProtocol+"://"+$scope.videoStreamer+"/&mp4:"+$scope.videoFile;                    
                return vm.clipDetails;
            });
        }

        var setupOpt = {
            'controls' : true,
            'autoplay' : true,
            'preload' : 'auto',
            // 'poster' : asset.thumbnail,
            'width' : '400',
            'height': '400'
        };

        //inject $sce to use any url, or fetch url from http request
        var vidSrc = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.videoURL);

        //create video js player dynamically
        videojs( 'myVideo', setupOpt, function(){
           $scope.vid = videojs( 'myVideo' ).src([ {type: "rtmp/mp4", src: vidSrc} ]);
        });

        //destroy video when $scope is destroyed
        $scope.$on( '$destroy', function() {
            console.log( 'destroying video player' );
            $scope.vid.dispose();
        });
  }]).directive('videodir',function(){
        var linkFn;

        linkFn = function (scope, element, attrs){
               videojs("myVideo",{"techOrder": ["html5","flash"]},function(){
                    this.src({type: "rtmp/mp4", src: scope.video.videoURL});
                    console.log(':::URL:::', scope.video.videoURL);
                });
                console.log('linkfn');
            };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: linkFn
    }
});
```

Even I am not able to get `$scope.videoURL` outside `activate()`. Am I using `promise` correctly ?

[image]

**What am I doing wrong here ? How to bind video URL via directive or via controller? Which way is better?**

Comment: `var vidSrc = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.videoURL);` : this line returns a promise or it returns undefined... maybe that is the issue?

Comment: @kukkuz that line is returning blank string.

Comment: another one: the directive has one issue: `scope.video.videoURL` is directive's scope and not $scope of the controller

Comment: @kukkuz that's where I am confused. how do I get videoURL in controller's scope and bind it to directive ?

Comment: `videodir="{{video.videoURL}}"` in html and then you can use `attrs.videodir` in the directive...

Comment: @kukkuz thanks for the swift replies. could you please modify my code whatever is wrong is there in your answer ? I will immediately try out and let you know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117822/discussion-between-valay-desai-and-kukkuz).